# How to load python files from ../

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I was wondering how would I load a python module from a file from the directory before the one the script is running on.

Example:

```
../
├── api
│   ├── Group.py
│   ├── Trade.py
│   └── User.py
├── client.py
```

How would Group.py import client.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for different directory you can use

import the module using the syntax

> from foldername.filename import *

```
from api.Group import *
```

if files are in same folder use directly

> use import followed by filename

```
import Group
```

Answer (score 1):

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python36\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Python36', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
```

If we observe the first `''` refers to the current folder, so why we can import the files from current path.
To import from parent we add the parent folder to the `sys.path` variable

```
>>> import os
>>> sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("./.."))
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python36\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Python36', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages', 'D:\\Python Programs\\Practice_Imports\\stack']
```

Now `sys.path` contains the parent folder, so we can import the `client.py` from `Group.py`

```
>>> import client
```

Check this [link](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#basics-of-the-python-import-and-syspath) for clear details for importing.